# how to call this url in java resful web service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, oop, collections

Can anyone help me ? In this scenario , how to call this service url in java restfull web service ?http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to fetch the data from this URL, in order to achieve this you can use HttpClient or simply you can use URL Connection to fetch data from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a Java client already written?  If not you can write your own using either [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) or [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) (other HTTP libraries are available).

If you are calling from inside the Spring container (as you tagged this question with the Spring tag) you can used the Spring [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-android/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String theUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments";
     StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
      // create a url object
      URL url = new URL(theUrl);

      // create a urlconnection object
      URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

      // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

      String line;

      // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
      {
        content.append(line + "\n");
      }
      bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(content);
  }
```